# does attr() always apply last one style or not?

Tags: jquery

i am new in jquery i want to know that i am trying to apply style using attr() i have given four style but it is applying last one style i want to know that does it always apply last one style or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p id="prg1">first paragraph</p>
   
</body>

<script src="C:\Users\SUDARSHAN\Desktop\html_UI\jquery-3.6.0.js">


</script>
<script>
   $('document').ready(function (){

      $('#prg1').attr({style:'color:yellow',style:'font-family:arial',style:'color:yellow',style:'border-style:dotted'});
     
      

   })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `style` attribute is a single string containing many styles like this

```html
<div style="color:yellow; font-family:arial; border-style:dotted">
```

So every time you apply it you're replacing the last string. So you'd have to do the following with one big string.

```js
$('#prg1').attr('color:yellow; font-family:arial; border-style:dotted')
```

However, this really isn't the best use case for `attr()`.

Instead, use the JQuery [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method which can set (and get) styles.

```js
$('#prg1')
  .css('color', 'yellow')
  .css('font-family', 'arial')
  .css('border-style', 'dotted')
```

or you can use an object in a single call

```js
$('#prg1').css({
  'color': 'yellow'
  'font-family': 'arial',
  'border-style': 'dotted'
})
```

Comment: can i use priority to apply style in attr() like first one style or second one style or third one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by priority. Using the `css()` method will apply multiple styles to the `style` attribute at once or even at different times. It will append new styles, it won't replace the styles like `attr()` will.

Comment: it means can i apply specific style given in attr()?

Comment: does atrr() apply last one style every time in any situation if i gave multiple styles there in atrr()?

Comment: @SudarshanPatil Using `attr()` with the same attribute multiple times replaces, it does not combine. This is because the javascript object you're using has a `style` field defined multiple times which is not allowed in javascript; fields must be uniquely named. Use the `css()` method instead to apply multiple styles at once.

Comment: sir i know this but i wanted to know that if there is duplicate key in attr() then will it always apply last one duplicate key?

Comment: @SudarshanPatil Yes, but that's not attr() behaviour, that's javascript behaviour. Javascript objects (like you're using) cannot have two keys with the same name and you should never make an object like that even if you weren't using attr() or jquery.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `.addClass()`

**jquery**

```
  $('document').ready(function (){
        $("#prg1").addClass("important");
   });
```

**css**

```
<style>
  .important {
    color:yellow;font-family:arial; color:yellow; border-style:dotted;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: While this may be a better approach, this isn't what OP is asking to do and they may have reasons for that.